# Why concatenation of String object and string literal is created in heap?

Tags: java, string

I have below Strings

```
String str1 = "Abc";//created in constant pool
String str2 = "XYZ";//created in constant pool
String str3 = str1 + str2;//created in constant pool
String str4 = new String("PQR");//created in heap
String str5 = str1.concat(str4);//created in heap 
String str6 = str1 + str4;//created in heap
```

Here I don't know why concatenation of Strings, one created in the constant pool, and the other in the heap, results in creating the new `String` in the heap. I don't know the reason, why does it happen?

Comment: what I know `pool is inside Heap memory`, not sure if there are any recent chanegs

Comment: @roottraveller the link you shared is about hash code and i want to know about memory locations

Comment: @roottraveller, constant pool is a part of `.class` in-memory representation, which means it's placed in PermGen area (or MetaSpace, starting from Java 8)

Comment: @YogeshKatkar, every *new* object is created inside the heap. Constant pool contains values which can not be changed, so when you concatenate a `String` from the constant pool and a `String` from the heap, you basically create a new `String` object which is placed on the heap.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov - Actually, it is in the main heap starting with Java 8.  Metaspace is a special heap that is used for code, class descriptors and so on.  Things that can't be relocated.

Comment: @StephenC, isn't constant pool a part of a class descriptor?

Comment: It may or may not be.  But this is not the "constant pool" that the OP is referring to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a bunch of dubious information in the comments, so I will give this a proper answer.

1. There is actually *no such thing* as "the constant pool".  You won't find this term in the Java Language Specification.

   (Perhaps you are getting your terminology confused with the Constant Pool which is the section of a `.class` file, and the corresponding per-class Runtime Constant Pool ... which is not visible to application programs.  These are "specification artifacts" defined by the JVM spec for the purpose of defining the execution model of bytecodes.  The spec does not require that they physically exist, though they typically do; e.g. in an Oracle or OpenJDK implementation.)
2. There is a *data structure* in a running JVM called the *string pool*.  The string pool is NOT mentioned by name in the JLS, but its existence is implied by string literal properties as specified by the JLS.  The string pool is mentioned in the javadocs, and the JVM specification.
3. The string pool will contain the `String` objects that represent the values of any string-valued constant expression used in an application.  This includes string literals.
4. The string pool has always been *primarily* a de-duping mechanism for strings.  Applications are able to use this by calling the `String.intern` method.
5. The string values in the Constant Pool (see above) are used to create the `String` objects that the application see:

   - A `String` object is created from the representation.
   - `String.intern` is called, returning the corresponding de-duped `String` object from the string pool.
   - That string becomes part of the classes Runtime Constant Pool; i.e. the Runtime Constant Pool for a class will include a reference to the String object in the string pool.
   - This process can happen eagerly or lazily depending on the Java implementation.
6. The string pool is and has always been stored in the (or a) heap.

   - Prior to Java 7, string objects in the string pool were allocated in a special heap called the PermGen heap.  In the earliest versions of Java it wasn't GC'ed.  Then it was GC'ed only occasionally.
   - In Java 7 (not 8!) the string pool stopped using the PermGen heap and used the regular heap instead.
   - In Java 8 the PermGen heap was replaced (for some purposes!) by a different storage management mechanism called the Metaspace.  Apparently, Metaspace doesn't hold Java objects.  Rather, it holds code segments, class descriptors and other JVM internal data structures.
7. In recent versions of Java (i.e. Java 8 u20 and later) the GC has another mechanism for de-duping strings that survive a given number of GC cycles.
8. The behavior of strings (i.e. which ones are interned and which ones are not) is determined by the relevant parts of the JLS and the javadocs for the String class.
9. All of the complexity is irrelevant if you follow one simple rule:

   > Never use `==` to compare strings.  Always use `equals`.

---

Now to deal with your example code:

```
String str1 = "Abc";               // string pool

String str2 = "XYZ";               // string pool

String str3 = str1 + str2;         // not string pool (!!)

String str3a = "Abc" + "XYZ";      // string pool 

String str4 = new String("PQR");   // not string pool (but the "PQR" literal is)

String str5 = str1.concat(str4);   // not string pool 

String str6 = str1 + str4;         // not string pool

String str7 = str6.intern();       // string pool
```

Why?

- The values assigned to `str1`, `str2` and `str3a` are all values of constant expressions; see below.
- The value assigned to `str3` is not the value of a constant expression according to the JLS.
- `str4` - the JLS says that `new` operator always creates a new object and new strings are not automatically interned
- `str5` - string operations apart from `intern` do not create objects in the string pool
- `str6` - ditto - equivalent to a `concat` call.   The JLS also says that `+` produces a *new* string (except in the constant expression case).
- `str7` - the exception: see above.  The `intern` call returns a object in the string pool.

Constant expressions include literals, concatenations involving literals, values of `static final String` constants, and a few other things.   See [JLS 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) for the complete list, but bear in mind that the string pool only holds string values.

---

The precise behavior of `intern` depends on the Java version.  Consider this example:

```
char[] chars = // create an array of random characters
String s1 = new String(chars);
String s2 = s1.intern();
```

Let us assume that the random characters do not correspond to any previously interned string.

- For older JVMs where interned strings were allocated in PermGen, the `intern` call in the example will (must) produce a new `String` object.
- For newer JVMs, the `intern` can add the existing String object to the string pool data structure without having to create a new `String` object.

In other words, the truth of `s1 == s2` depends on the Java version.

Comment: This is a great explanation about strings i have a very clear idea now

Comment: It’s misleading to say “PermGen heap was replaced by a different heap called the Metaspace”. As you said yourself, the Metaspace doesn’t contain any Java objects, so it’s not a heap memory. For the same reason, Java objects formerly stored in the PermGen are now all placed into the Old Gen or whatever equivalent of the particular configured GC algorithm. Hence, Metaspace is not a direct replacement. By the way, `String str7 = str6.intern();` may cause the addition of the string referenced by `str6` to the pool, in which case `str6 == str7` but it may also return a different instance instead.

Comment: OK.  So now you have told me a few things I didn't know.  Can you point me (us) at some public documentation that explains what the metaspace really is?

Comment: Don’t know a canonical pointer, i.e. an official document eventually describing the metaspace. One helpful pointer is [the RFE describing the JVM implementation change](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046112), “*Move part of the contents of the permanent generation in Hotspot to the Java heap and the remainder to native memory.* … *The proposed implementation will allocate class meta-data in native memory and move interned Strings and class statics to the Java heap. Hotspot will explicitly allocate and free the native memory for the class meta-data.*”

Comment: Combine this with [JVMS, §2.5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3), the only place where an actual definition of Java Heap is made: “*The heap is the run-time data area from which memory for all class instances and arrays is allocated.*” Given this definition, I wouldn’t call the native memory containing class metadata (and no Java objects) part of the heap memory.